# ANTLR parser and tree grammars for one simple language

Tags: c#, parsing, tree, antlr

Edit:

Here is the updated tree and parser grammars:

parser grammar:

```
    options {

language = CSharp2;

output=AST;


}
tokens {
UNARY_MINUS;
CALL;
}
program :   (function)* main_function

        ;



function:       'function' IDENTIFIER '(' (parameter (',' parameter)*)? ')' 'returns' TYPE declaration* statement* 'end' 'function'
        ->    ^('function' IDENTIFIER parameter* TYPE declaration* statement*)
    ;

main_function
    :   'function' 'main' '(' ')' 'returns' TYPE declaration* statement*  'end' 'function'
    ->    ^('function' 'main' TYPE declaration* statement*)   
    ;   

parameter
    :   'param' IDENTIFIER ':' TYPE
    ->    ^('param' IDENTIFIER TYPE)
    ;

declaration
    :       'variable' IDENTIFIER ( ',' IDENTIFIER)* ':' TYPE ';'
    ->    ^('variable' TYPE IDENTIFIER+ )
    |       'array' array  ':' TYPE ';'
    ->    ^('array' array TYPE)
    ;

statement 
    : ';'! | block | assignment | if_statement | switch_statement | while_do_statement | for_statement | call_statement | return_statement  
    ;

call_statement
    :   call ';'!
    ;

return_statement
    :   'return' expression ';'
    ->    ^('return' expression)
    ;

block   : 'begin' declaration* statement* 'end'
        -> ^('begin' declaration* statement*)
        |  '{' declaration* statement* '}'
        -> ^('{' declaration* statement*)
    ;

assignment 
    :   IDENTIFIER ':=' expression ';'
        ->      ^(':=' IDENTIFIER expression )
    |       array ':=' expression ';'
    ->     ^(':=' array expression) 
    ;

array   :   IDENTIFIER '[' expression (',' expression)* ']'
    ->  ^(IDENTIFIER expression+)
    ;

if_statement 
    :   'if' '(' expression ')' 'then' statement ('else' statement)? 'end' 'if'
    ->    ^('if' expression statement statement?)

    ;

switch_statement 
    :   'switch' '(' expression ')' case_part+ ('default' ':' statement)? 'end' 'switch'
    ->    ^('switch' expression case_part+ statement?)
    ; 

case_part
    :   'case' literal (',' literal)* ':' statement
    ->    ^('case' literal+ statement)
    ;

literal 
    :   INTEGER | FLOAT | BOOLEAN | STRING
    ; 

while_do_statement
    :   'while' '(' expression ')' 'do' statement 'end' ' while'
    ->    ^('while' expression statement)
    ;

for_statement 
    :       'for' '(' IDENTIFIER ':=' expression 'to' expression ')' 'do' statement 'end' 'for'
    ->   ^('for' IDENTIFIER expression expression statement)
    ;

expression
    :   conjuction ( 'or'^ conjuction)*
    ;

conjuction
    :       equality ('and'^ equality)* 
    ;

equality:   relation (('=' | '/=')^ relation)?
        ;

relation:   addition (('<' | '<=' | '>' | '>=')^ addition)?
    ;

addition:   multiplication (('+' | '-')^ multiplication)*   
    ;

multiplication
    :   unary_operation (('*' | '/' | '%')^ unary_operation)*
    ;
unary_operation
    :   '-' primary 
    ->   ^(UNARY_MINUS primary)
    |        'not' primary 
    ->   ^('not' primary)
    |     primary
    ;

primary :   IDENTIFIER 
        | array 
        |  literal 
        | '('! expression ')'!  
        | '(' TYPE ')'  '(' expression ')'
        -> ^(TYPE expression) 
        |  call
    ; 

call    :   IDENTIFIER '(' arguments ')'
        ->     ^(CALL IDENTIFIER arguments)
    ;

arguments
    :   (expression  (','! expression)*)? 
    ;

BOOLEAN :   'true' | 'false'
    ;   

T    YPE    : 'integer' | 'boolean' | 'float' | 'string' | 'array' | 'void'
    ;

IDENTIFIER  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
    ;

INTEGER :   '0'..'9'+
    ;

FLOAT
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')+ 
    ;

COMMENT
    :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    |   '/*' ( options {greedy=false;} : . )* '*/' {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

WS  :   ( ' '
        | '\t'
        | '\r'
        | '\n'
        ) {$channel=HIDDEN;}
    ;

STRING
    :  '"' .* '"'
    ;
```

And here is the updated tree grammar (I altered expressions, and so on...):

```
    options {
language = 'CSharp2';
//tokenVocab= token vocab needed
ASTLabelType=CommonTree; // what is Java type of nodes?

}
program :   (function)* main_function

        ;



function:     ^('function' IDENTIFIER parameter* TYPE declaration* statement*)
    ;

main_function
    :   ^('function' 'main' TYPE declaration* statement*)   
    ;   

parameter
    :   ^('param' IDENTIFIER TYPE)
    ;

declaration
    :     ^('variable' TYPE IDENTIFIER+)
        |     ^('array' array TYPE  )
    ;

statement 
    : block | assignment | if_statement | switch_statement | while_do_statement | for_statement | call_statement | return_statement 
    ;

call_statement
    :   call 
    ;

return_statement
    :   ^('return' expression)
    ;

block   : ^('begin' declaration* statement*)
        |  ^('{' declaration* statement*)
    ;

assignment 
    :   ^(':=' IDENTIFIER expression )
    |      ^(':=' array expression) 
    ;

array   :   ^(IDENTIFIER expression+)
    ;

if_statement 
    :   ^('if' expression statement statement?)

    ;

switch_statement 
    :   ^('switch' expression case_part+ statement?)
    ; 

case_part
    :   ^('case' literal+ statement)
    ;

literal 
    :   INTEGER | FLOAT | BOOLEAN | STRING
    ; 

while_do_statement
    :   ^('while' expression statement)
    ;

for_statement 
    :    ^('for' IDENTIFIER expression expression statement)
    ;

expression
    :   ^('or' expression expression)
    |      ^('and' expression expression)
    |      ^('=' expression expression)   
    |      ^('/=' expression expression)
    |       ^('<' expression expression)
    |       ^('<=' expression expression)
    |       ^('>' expression expression)
    |       ^('>=' expression expression)
    |       ^('+' expression expression)
    |       ^('-' expression expression)
    |      ^(UNARY_MINUS expression)
    |      ^('not' expression)
    |      IDENTIFIER
    |      array
    |       literal 
        |      ^(TYPE expression) 
        |      call
    ;

call    :   ^(CALL IDENTIFIER arguments)
    ;

arguments
    :   (expression  (expression)*)? 
    ;
```

I succesfluly generated tree graph with DOTTreeGenerator and StringTemplate classes so it seems that all is working at the moment. But any suggestions (about bad habits or something else in this grammars) are appreciated since I don't have a lot of experience with ANTLR or language recognition.

See updates on http://vladimir-radojicic.blogspot.com

Comment: Please provide the tree parser rule for your addition, too. Otherwise it's hard to tell what's going wrong.

Comment: That is impossible to tell without seeing the entire parser- and tree-grammar.

Comment: May I somehow send you whole grammar, since addition rule is calling another , and another and another rule, so it is whole grammar almost?

Comment: You can edit your original question and add both parser- and tree-grammars.

Comment: Here it is - parser and tree grammar I am using ANTLRWorks 1.4, and not 1.4.2 since at the moment it has some bugs when generating C# code

Comment: @Vladimir, there are quite a few things wrong with your tree grammar (and some "bad habits" in the combined grammar as well...). I don't have time to go into them now. Perhaps tomorrow.

Comment: Ok, thanks for help, I appreciate your help and suggestions. This is my first grammar since I read ANTLR reference :S

Comment: I edited grammars, and it is working now.

Comment: Cool, nice work! Sorry, I had to remove the DOT-output from your post since after indenting your grammars with four spaces (to get a bit of syntax-highlighting), the post exceeded the maximum number of characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I was going to suggest, besides introducing imaginary tokens to make sure your tree grammar produces a "unique AST" and simplifying the `expression` in the *tree*-grammar, which you both already did (again: well done!), is that you shouldn't use literal tokens inside your parser grammar. Especially not when they can possibly be matched by other lexer rule(s). For example, all your reserved words (like `for`, `while`, `end`, etc.) can also be matched by the lexer rule `IDENTIFIER`. It's better to create explicit tokens inside the lexer (and put these rules *before* the `IDENTIFIER` rule!):

```
...

FOR   : 'for'; 
WHILE : 'while'; 
END   : 'end';

...

IDENTIFIER  
  :  ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9'|'_')*
  ;

...
```

Ideally, the tree grammar does not contain any quoted tokens. AFAIK, you can't import grammar `X` inside a grammar `Y` properly: the literal tokens inside grammar `X` are then not available in grammar `Y`. And when you split your your combined grammar in a parser- and lexer grammar, these literal tokens are not allowed. With small grammars like your, these last remarks are of no concern to you (and you could leave your grammar "as is"), but remember them when you create larger grammars.

Best of luck!

### EDIT

Imaginary tokens are not only handy when there's no real token that can be made as root of the tree. The way I look at imaginary tokens is that they make your tree "unique", so that the tree grammar can only "walk" your tree in one possible way. Take subtraction and unary minus for example. If you wouldn't have created an imaginary token called `UNARY_MINUS`, but simply did this:

```
unary_operation
  :  '-' primary   -> ^('-' primary)
  |  'not' primary -> ^('not' primary)
  |  primary
  ;
```

then you'd have something like this in your tree grammar:

```
expression
  :  ^('-' expression expression)
  |  ...
  |  ^('-' expression)
  |  ...
  ;
```

Now both subtraction and unary minus start with the same tokens, which the tree grammar does not like! It's easy to see with this `-` (minus) example, but there can be quite some tricky cases (even with small grammars like yours!) that are not so obvious. So, always let the parser create "unique trees" while rewriting to AST's.

Hope that clarifies it (a bit).

Comment: Thank you very much on useful suggestions I really appreciate it!Firstly I wanted to get rid of all "syntactic sugar",so I tried to introduce as little additional imaginary tokens as possible,since it doesn't carry any crucial information about source code, it just adds some additional rules in my grammar. But now I see that I shouldn't run away from it.But imaginary tokens are "syntactic sugar",am I right?For example,this source code variable declaration: int x,y; And in my parser grammar I make imaginary token VAR:  ^(VAR type ID+).Now I have more "sugar" in my AST then my source code?

Comment: many thanks on your explanations. Next I am planning to make code generator for this that will compile my language source code into Common Intermediate Language. I opened blog for this purpose on http://vladimir-radojicic.blogspot.com/ so I hope I will publish that part of the work next month if I succeed, since it is all new world to me. :)